# Padding/Line-Height/Height won't increase height of HTML input element

Tags: html, css

### How can I increase the height of the submit button?

I would like it to match the height of the text area to its left? I've seen answers recommending *padding, line-height and even the height attribute*.

However, none of these seem to work for me. Does it have something to do with Flexbox? Regardless, I can't seem to figure it out. I swear the last time I created a form, the css height property seemed to work for input elements...

```css
#chatbox {
    width: 500px;
    background-color: #93ff95;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#loginContainer {
    text-align: right;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
}

#loginContainer input {
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

input#login {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: none;
    color: blue;
    border: none;
}

#loginForm {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

#messagesArea {
    height: 350px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 5px;
    overflow: auto;
}

#messageInputArea {
    height: 100px; 
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

#messageForm {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 1;
    margin: auto;
    min-height: 60%;
    min-width: 80%;
}

#messageBox {
    min-width: 80%;
    /*flex: 5;*/
    /*margin: 0 10px 0 0;*/
}

#stupidButton {
    min-width: 10%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 15px 5px; 
    /*flex: 1;*/
    height: 100%;
}

#messageBoxBlocked {
    width: 85%;
    height: 85%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: auto;
    display: none;
    padding: 0 10px;
    
}
```

```html
        <h1>Chat with Customer Service</h1>
        <div id="chatbox">
            <div id="loginContainer">
                <form id='loginForm'>
                    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter a username"/>
                    <input id="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Login"/>
                </form>
    
            </div>
            <div id="messagesArea">
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
               <p>Admin: Hey Everyone!</p>
            </div>
            <div id="messageInputArea">
                <button id="messageBoxBlocked">Log in to enter chat</button>
                <form id="messageForm">
                    <input id="messageBox" name="messageBox" placeholder="Enter your message here"/>
                    <input id="stupidButton" type="submit" name="Send"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` to input `#stupidButton`

Comment: It's working as expected in FF

Comment: But it looks like it works in Chrome Windows 10. Are you using Safari?

Comment: @zer00ne, it isn't working in Chrome OSX

Comment: @PavKR then it's a Mac Webkit bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as you're expecting in Firefox but in webkit browsers (Chrome, Safari etc.) it doesn't, this is presumably because they have extra styling information that they apply to form elements. Try adding `-webkit-appearance: none` to the input button, this should remove all the default styling for the button.

Comment: +1 What the heck.. that fixes the problem!... could you further elaborate.. I've never encountered this situation before.. is this just with form controls? I also thought the -webkit- tags were no longer necessary..

Comment: Also what's weird is the input at the top of the page "enter username" works fine with the CSS height property.. so this is only related to input type=submit?

Comment: @GovindRai, AFAIK it only applies to form elements, Chrome and Safari apply visual enhancements to form elements which can be removed by `-webkit-appearance: none`. For example, if you were to use an input type 'search' it will be a different style to input type 'text'.

Answer (score -1):

For me it looks exactly the same height. Please specify browser and/or provide the picture of how it should look.